# Slice a dataframe based on a specific range repeated over a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a dataframe with one of the columns having a counter. The counter goes from 0-127 and is repeated. The start and end of dataframe can have sliced counters, for example first row could start with 32 but would end at 127, then 0-127 repeated slices and the last slice could end abruptly not necessarily being 127. Something like follows,

32
33
.
.
127
0
1
.
.
127
0
1
.
.
127
0
1
.
15

**Is there a way I could slice the dataframe into different sets, each containing 128 rows?**

Comment: If you are asking how to randomly slice into new df's with 128 rows, the answer is yes. Can you provide the DF and the desired outcome? It is a little difficult to follow.

Comment: @justin-oberle No, not randomly but based on the counter value. so 32-127 would be sbset 1, next 0-127 would be subset 2, next 0-127 subset 3 and last subset would consist of only 15 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if the total number of rows is not a multiple of 128, no you will no be able to slice the dataframe in subsets each containing exactly 128 rows.

But it is trivial to slice the dataframe in slices of 128 rows, the last of them having *at most* 128 rows with `iloc`:

```
for i in range(0, len(df), 128):
    subset = df.iloc[i:i+128]
    # process subset...
```

If you want to slice *according* to the counter column, with the first and last slices having at most 128 rows, you could use a GroupBy:

```
groups = df.groupby((df['counter'] == 0).cumsum())
for i, g in groups:
    print('Processing group', i)
    subset = g
    # process subset
```

Comment: but the first and last slices aren't exactly 128, so based on the **counter value** I want to get only rows from 0 to 128 for each subset.